# How to remove the requested vars in PHP5

Tags: variables, php-5.3

I have a HTML table with a list of database records in every row and in everyone of them a form with the information needed to delete the record in the database with its submit button (method POST).

So I get the values from the global var $_POST. My issue is that when I click in any of those submit buttons it is thrown a cascade or recursive delete and all the records are deleted.

I have been googling but I have not found anything. I saw code like unset($_POST['myvar']) but it does not work.

How could I resolve this?

Regards,
oggie0563

Comment: Post some snippets of your code!

Comment: What does your POST look like? You probably want to filter and validate the input and transform it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

It is a PRG problem. I've found this,

[php-postredirectget-class](http://patrickdawkins.com/web-development/php-postredirectget-class/)

Maybe this is enough.

Comment: It is a Patrick Dawkins development. Thanks and I hope it helps to any other one.